# How to get the correct format of dateand time in mysql?

Tags: java, mysql

When I get the date and time in MySQL it retrieves it in this format:

```
2016-01-14 14:24:00.0
```

Where does the  `.0` come from and how do I get this format with Java:

```
2016-01-14 14:24:00
```

Comment: Can you show the code how you get the date from the database with Java?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use 2 ways to do this.

1. Split the date string at '.'

   ```
   String date = "2016-01-14 14:24:00.0";
   String newDate = date.split("\\.")[0];
   System.out.println(newDate);
   ```
2. Use SimpleDateFormat

   ```
   SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS");
   Date date = sdf.parse("2016-01-14 14:24:00.0");
   sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
   System.out.println(sdf.format(date));
   ```

Comment: it's a good try sorry but i don't need these two methods from my project

Comment: .0 specifies the milliseconds and the 2nd method I have shown will remove it. What else was needed?

Answer (score 0):

If you are getting date as string, you can use `Format` to get the format you need:

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(YourDateField, '%d-%m-%Y %T')
FROM YourTable
```

Have a look [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format) for all possible formats

Answer (score 0):

If you are getting your date as a `java.sql.Timestamp`, you can get the corresponding `java.util.Date` instance very easily and then format it to the desired string representation with a `java.text.SimpleDateFormat` class.